# Related Key/Value table indexing / search

Tags: mysql, laravel, indexing, elasticsearch, key-value

I have table 'elements' that is related with table 'element_parameters'. element_parameters table have key/value structure. Keys and values are dynamicaly, they can be created be user or by some software, so I can't predefine them in 'elements' table.

For example I have elements 'flower' and 'car':

```
elements
--------
flower
car

element_parameters
------------------
element | key          | value
flower  | smell        | soft
car     | manufacturer | fiat
flower  | color        | red
car     | wheels       | 4
```

As you can see, there could be any keys and any values.

But often I need to find elements by their parameters. This is the problem. One element could have 10000+ parameters. So if I have 100 elements, I have to search through 1000000 parameters each time i want to find some element. And i can't do this in one query, be cause first I have to find all parameters thats fits my condition, group them by parameter ID and then search elements table for those ID's.

Is there some search engines, where I could merge and index elements with their parameters to 'one row'? Elasticsearch would be good decision for this situation? Maybe there is other ways to solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post an example of a set of conditions that describe your problem. It's unclear if you want to search elements only via their parameter keys or also their values.

Comment: Both. Application is pretty complex. Sometimes I need to find some element that have for example 'manufacturer = 'fiat' and color = 'red'. Generaly, I need to store them in key/value format to keep parameters dynamic, but when I searching for element, I need to use logic like they would be in one row.

Comment: EAV schema sucks.  But here are some hints:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your db like this:

```
elements
-----------
id | name
1  | flower
2  | car


element_parameters
-------------------------------------------------
element_id | parameters                    
1          | {"color":"red","smell":"soft"}
2          | {"manufacturer": "fiat", "wheels":3}
```

You can find easily any element's parameter:

```
$id = 1;
$element = Element::find($id)->load('ElementParameters')->get();
$paremeters = json_decode($element->ElementParameters);
```

Comment: No it's not a solution. Flower doesn't have manufacturer and wheels. Like i said, parameters are dynamic, so I cannot predefine them in table.

Comment: I modified the code. If you store the parameters in json? I think this is the fastest solution.

Comment: Storing them as JSON will impede the ability to build queries that search elements by parameters.

Comment: Exactly, I can't search element by its parameters where they will be stored in json format.